# Implementing a CNN Deep Learning Model in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I apologize in advance if anything about the structure of my question or the way I’m asking it isn’t exactly correct; this is my first time asking a question on here.

**The Problem**

I’ve built a GUI application for my research position that interfaces with a radar sensor’s API in order to perform real-time imaging in a variety of formats (this uses C++/Qt). My next step will be architecting and implementing a CNN that will essentially take in image data retrieved by the sensor and perform binary classification on it. For the past week or so, I’ve had an absolutely horrible time attempting to include any kind of mainstream deep learning framework in my pre-existing app.

**What I’ve Tried**

- TensorFlow

My first thought was to employ TensorFlow (due to its popularity) to construct my network in Python and then load the model into my C++ app. Unfortunately, I’ve been completely unable to include TensorFlow in my app properly due to a lack of any kind of clear documentation or instruction on how to do so.

- PyTorch

After beating my head against a wall for a few days with TensorFlow, I figured I’d try a similar approach with PyTorch because I heard plenty of people commending it for being more user-friendly and intuitive. Once again, trying to include the PyTorch C++ API in my app has been a total nightmare. All I can find in the docs are a couple tutorials in which CMake is used to generate a new project, but for obvious reasons, this wouldn’t work for my use case.

I feel like I’m chasing my tail at this point; my next thought is to try again with another kind of deep learning framework, but I feel like I’ll fall right back into this same issue of being unable to include the library in my pre-existing app. Any recommendations/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I’ve been completely unable to include TensorFlow in my app" - what have you tried? How exactly did it not work?

Comment: I tried following several different sources of instruction (the shallow docs, a few different articles, YouTube videos) that attempt to show the process of downloading the TensorFlow library and linking it in a CPP project. I ended up building TensorFlow from source per the doc’s instructions, but don’t know where to go from there and haven’t been able to find any resources explaining how to do so.